# How to pop None from serializer.data in python?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

When i looping through **serializer.data** is shows **None** inside that. I want to pop None from that.

If I have:

```
serializer.data = OrderedDict([('customer', OrderedDict([('name', 'Sachin'), ('email', 
                  'abc@gmail.com'), ('created_at','2021-03-12T15:04:25.695147+05:30'), 
                  ('updated_at','2021-03-12T15:04:25.695147+05:30'), ('user', 9)]))])
                  None
                  OrderedDict([('customer', OrderedDict([('name', 'Sachin'), ('email', 
                  'abc@gmail.com'), ('created_at', '2021-03-12T15:04:25.695147+05:30'), 
                  ('updated_at', '2021-03-12T15:04:25.695147+05:30'), ('user', 9)]))])
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your `serializer.data` is a `list`, you can use `filter` to eliminate `None`

```py
list_without_none = list(filter(lambda x: x is not None, serializer.data))
```

See about `filter` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_filter.asp)